# C++ event system with templates - how to store subscriber functions taking arbitrary type?

Tags: c++, templates, events, stl

I'm trying to write an event system using templates for flexibility and std::strings as event IDs. I want to be able to fire an event with an argument of any type and then a list of functions handles the event. My problem is I'm not very familiar with templates, so I can't figure out how to store a list of subscriber functions which take an arbitrary type.

I'm basically trying to do this, it's completely invalid pseudocode, but you should get the general idea of the resulting system I want:

```
template<typename T> std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::function<void(T)>>> subscribers;

template<typename T> void subscribe(std::string event_id, std::function<void(T)> f)
{
    subscribers<T>[event_id].push_back(f);
}

template<typename T> void fire(std::string event_id, T data)
{
    for (auto f : subscribers<T>[event_id])
        f(data);
}

...

void handle_test_event(int data)
{
    printf("%d", data);
}

subscribe<int>("test event", handle_test_event);

fire<int>("test event", 123);
```

What are the proper methods and syntax to achieve something functionally equivalent to the pseudocode?

Comment: [This works pretty much as written](https://godbolt.org/z/GGhCze). What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your works without any modification, assuming you provide the proper `#include`s. The only thing that you should probably improve is to channge the `auto` to `auto&` and the `push_back(f)` to `push_back(std::move(f))`.

Comment: I got a freaky template error trying to it earlier... tried again apparently it does work now, weird

Comment: I am voting to close the question since there isn't really any answerable problem left in the question. The pseudo-code is actual working code that behaves in the intended way.

Comment: It might be worth asking about the type erasure necessary to make `subscribers` not be a global variable.